# how to share using default sharing in marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, sharing

I did code to share image,so i used default sharing code as per below.it works fine in all device.but i can not share in marshmallow OS device's app.

Code:

```
    Uri imageuri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); 
    Intent send_report = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{PrefexamList.getString(App.PEMAIL, "")}); 
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Result");
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
    send_report.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here attached Your result.");  
    send_report.setType("text/plain");
    send_report.setType("image/png");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(send_report, "Choose an Email client"), 77);
```

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the run time permission. Android marshmallow require run time permission for access the image files stored in the device. So you need to give run time permission in code. Please visit

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i did all runtime permition related to storage.can you suggest me which permition have been missing?

Comment: what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: targetSdkVersion=23

Comment: would you please change it to 22 and check

Comment: is it installed in marshmallow devices  if i published signed apk to play store?

Comment: yha, if we change targetSdkVersion=22, then also it is possible to install in marshmallow devices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120689/discussion-between-vasant-and-shanto-george).